# Deleting a list item when it's clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to delete an item from a `<ul>` when the user clicks on it. Here is my `List` component right now:

```
class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        //What goes here?
    }

    render() {
        const list = this.props.items.map((x, index) => {
            return <li key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>{index+1}. {x}</li>
        });

        return (
            <ul className="list">
                {list}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

The `handleClick` function runs when the user clicks on one of the `<li>` elements. How can I get the `{index}` of the element that called the function, and then use that to delete it from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Use an [`JS#arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [`JS#function curry`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying).

```
const list = this.props.items.map((x, index) => {
      return <li key={index} onClick={(index) => this.handleClick(index)}>{index + 1}. {x}</li>
    });
```

This will create a new function that calls `handleClick` with given params

**handleClick:** with function curry.

```
handleClick = (event) => { // get event
  return function (indexLI) {
    console.log(indexLI); //get index
    //your logic to delete item for LI and update state here
  }
}
```

`handleClick` will have both user defined params and event object

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you suggest a better key, as I know you are not supposed to use `{index}` but I'm not sure what else would work in this case.

Comment: yes `Index as a key is an anti-pattern`,it should have a permanent and unique property from list like hash value or primary key id from database,but should not be index from collection

Comment: @JakAttk123 event you can use `uuid or shortid` npm packages